# Change attribute value basing on existing value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'll illustrate with an example:
I need to convert the following html with javascript

```
<a href="aaa.kmz"></a>
<a href="eee.kmz"></a>
<a href="rrr.kmz"></a>
...
```

to code where all href values has changed only the last letter

```
<a href="aaa.kml"></a>
<a href="eee.kml"></a>
<a href="rrr.kml"></a>
...
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) & [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: I know how to retrieve a value of attribute and obviously it's simple to add something to this value but in this case I need to 'go inside'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the a tags, loop through them and replace `.kmz` with `.kml`:

```
​var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0, l = tags.length; i < l; i++) {
    tags[i].href = tags[i].href.replace('.kmz', '.kml');
}​​​​
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Ln4s4/